# a string to a dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I want to create a dictionary of dictionary but I can't for a text and in an iterative way…. and I am obligated to create a lot of variable and I want that the creation of the dictionary to be automatical without the creation of variables. Can you help me to improve it ?

I tried to create two functions and create this dictionary with one word…

```
def create_last_dictionary(word, n):
dico={}
dico[word[len(word) - n]] = {}
return dico

def create_dictionary(dic_to_add, word, n):
dic = {}
dic[word[len(word) - n]]=dic_to_add
return dic

word = "mommy"

one = create_last_dictionary(word, 1) 
two = create_dictionary(one, word, 2)
three = create_dictionary(two, word, 3)
four = create_dictionary(three, word, 4)
five = create_dictionary(four, word, 5)
six = create_dictionary(five, word, 6)
seven = create_dictionary(six, word, 7)

result :
{'m': {'o': {'r': {'n': {'i': {'n': {'g': {}}}}}}}}
```

I want it for a list of words like : 
if the list is : ["good", "Morning", "mommy"]

I want the dictionary to be :

```
{{'g': {'o': {'o': {'d': {}}}}}, 'm': {'o': {'m': {'m': {'y': {}}}}, {'r': {'n': {'i': {'n': {'g': {}}}}}}}}

the representation of the dictionary :
{
 {'g': {'o': {'o': {'d': {}}}}}, 
 {'m': {'o': {{'m': {'m': {'y': {}}}}, 
              {'r': {'n': {'i': {'n': {'g': {}}}}}}}}}
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Comment: so basically you want to implement a trie that uses dictionary of dictionary structure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function which inserts a new word in an existing (maybe empty) tree.  To achieve this I propose a recursive function:

```
def insert(tree, path):
  if path:
    insert(tree.setdefault(path[0], {}), path[1:])
```

Now you can use it:

```
tree = {}
insert(tree, 'good')
insert(tree, 'morning')
insert(tree, 'mommy')
print(tree)
```

prints

```
{'m': {'o': {'m': {'m': {'y': {}}},
             'r': {'n': {'i': {'n': {'g': {}}}}}}},
 'g': {'o': {'o': {'d': {}}}}}
```

EDIT:

In case you don't like using `.setdefault()` because it seems a hard-to-read shortcut, consider this:

```
def insert(tree, path):
  if path:
    if path[0] not in tree:
      tree[path[0]] = {}
    insert(tree[path[0]], path[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chaining function calls, you could create a recursive function; your are almost there as you created two cases already. I found a course about Python recursive functions here: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_recursive_functions.php